# Restrictions in file types in FineUploader 3.7.0

Tags: fine-uploader

I am using the option "allowedExtensions" without any problem but there is a situation where I have to permit any type of extension but two.

Is there a simple way to do that? I didn't find an option like 'restrictedExtensions' to do that in the code.

Thanks

Comment: I've updated my answer below with some more robust code that won't fail if the file name has more than one dot, or if the file name is extensionless, or if the case of the file's extension doesn't exactly match the restriction extension's case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

> The `validate` and `validateBatch` events are thrown/called *before* the default Fine Uploader validators (defined in the options) execute.

Also, if your validation event handler returns `false`, then Fine Uploader will register that file as invalid and not submit it.

Here's some code you could try in your `validate` event handler. It has not been tested yet so YMMV.

```js
var notAllowedExts = ['pptx', 'xlsx', 'docx'];

/* ... */

    onValidate: function (fileOrBlobData) {
        var valid = true;
        var fileName = fileOrBlobData.name || '';
        qq.each(notAllowedExts, function(idx, notAllowedExt) {
            var extRegex = new RegExp('\\.' + notAllowedExt + "$", 'i');

            if (fileName.match(extRegex) != null) {
                valid = false;
                return false;
            }
        });
        return valid;
    }

/* ... */
```